# IBM Server IMM settings throughWMI

Tags: wmi, ibm

We have few windows servers 2008 where we need to find out IP Address of IMM module.
Is there any way we can query it using WMI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it directly with WMI, but you can definitely use WMI to remotely [execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782811/im-trying-to-run-a-command-using-wmi) the IBM ASU utility on the remote machine and obtain it's output, or write to a shared log.

-- ab1

Comment: Thanks Chainik...i will do some research on that. If you have some links on its usage please let me know. Strange since HP servers its possible through HP_managementProcesor namespace...Anyways Thanks!!!